# MultiLine Picker item in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to use a picker for selecting question from list of questions in picker item for mobile devices in Xamarin Forms. Some of these questions are long strings which does not fit in one line and so picker could not able to display complete question. Is there a way to handle this long string to adjust it into multi line based upon device width.

Answer (score -1):

What about ListView + SearcBar (modal page)?